# How can I get SqlLiteStudio to export to SQL file with tables in the correct order?

Tags: sqlite, export, sqlitestudio

I have a relational SQLite database with tables accessing each other via foreign keys.  When I use SqlLiteStudio "Export" to output to a new SQL file, it writes out SQL "CREATE" and "INSERT INTO" statements based on alphabetical order of table names.  When I then import the same SQL file into a new database (which requires use of the command "Execute SQL from File", because the import command seems to only import csv into a table), I get the "no such table" error, because the line to create the table being referenced is not yet read.  So if I edit the SQL file to put the tables at the top, then I get the "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" error.  So then if I edit the SQL file to all the tables insert operations below the table creations, AND reorder the inserts by table so that no table precedes its table dependencies, only then I can successfully import the SQL file, reproducing the original SQLite database file.  Seems like a bug in SqlLiteStudio.  I suppose worse case I can write a post-processing script, but I'm hoping to find out if there's some better method people are using.  I just prefer to save in text format for backup into an existing git repo, and also make it easier for db migration later.  TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could turn Foreign Key Support Off before the import and then back On after the import using

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off;
....
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

see https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys

Comment: That worked.  For the record, I created new empty database, and with it selected, opened SQL editor, typed in the keys off command here and hit F9 (execute query), then did the import as I mentioned in the original post, it imported with no errors(!!!), then I ran the keys on command.  So it's an SQLite thing, whereas I had thought it was a SQLiteStudio thing, so that explains why I didn't see it in their documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSeagoe by default SQLite has Foreign Keys off, but most of the SQLite tools, in including studio turn it on.

Comment: SQLiteStudio does add these 2 pragmas to the exported SQL file automatically.

Comment: @Googie it didn't work, at least for me...
https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio/issues/4343

Comment: Looks like it's a bug as it is getting fixed now.